# How to change all specified words in a file from upper to lower case at once in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a file in which I wrote many time the same word in upper case. I wanna modify all the words at once from upper to lower case, except those coming after a dot. Is that possible? I've found some tips here and there, but in all of them it is needed to place the cursor at the begging of the word.

Answer (score 5):

```
:%s/\.\@<!\<THEWORD\>/theword/g
```

Replace "`THEWORD`" and "`theword`" with the properly-cased equivalents of the actual word in question.

Comment: To avoid retyping the word, one can use `:%s/\.\@<!\<WORD\>/\L&/g`.

Answer (score 3):

```
:%s/.*/\L&/g
```

Of course it must be proper regular expression.
This one takes all(.*), the rest is up to you.

Details here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions

Answer (score 1):

```
:1,$s/\([^\.]\s\s*\)MYWORD/\1myword/g
```

This will replace all MYWORD with myword unless it follows a . and one or more spaces. This will not change MYWORD at the beginning of line. For those, you can run the following again:

```
:1,$s/^MYWORD/myword/
```